# Can't locate application data on Android phone

Tags: android

I have spent many hours trying to find/create files for an app I am writing.  When I pull the application directory name I get: /data/data/com.example.android.[myapp]/files.  I am using File(getFilesDir():

```
    File fileDir = new File(getFilesDir() + File.separator);
    Log.i(TAG, "File directory: "+fileDir);
```

When I try to find this path I find many application folders here: Android/data/com but no /data/data folder under Android.  There are many other application folders there but not mine.  I see the same results whether I use Android Files app or Windows Explorer over USB.  I've also tried to look using Eclipse DDMS tab. I see a data folder with a (+) to the left but when I click, it does not expand.

I have also tried creating the directory and file manually with Windows explorer and my app still can't find neither the Android/data/com.example... nor the Android/data/data/com.example... paths.

Also puzzling to me is when the app creates the path and file and write to it (using MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE) I get no exceptions thrown but then I am unable to read it back or see it with either of the tools mentioned above.  I have set the manifest permissions to WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE and WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE for the app.

Obviously, I am making a very basic mistake.

I am on Android 4.1.2 (API 16).

Sincerely,
ScratchingMyHead

Comment: Like Commonsware just said, you don't have access to the data/ folder with DDMS on your hardware, but if you root your device, or easier still, if you use the emulator, you will have access to that folder.

Answer (score 0):

To get the path of my application directory, Try this code sample

```
PackageManager m = getPackageManager();
String s = getPackageName();
try {
    PackageInfo p = m.getPackageInfo(s, 0);
    s = p.applicationInfo.dataDir;
} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
    Log.w("yourtag", "Error Package name not found ", e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> When I try to find this path I find many application folders here: Android/data/com but no /data/data folder under Android.

That is because you are looking on [external storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html), not [internal storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html) where your files are. Use DDMS on an emulator to examine internal storage.

> I've also tried to look using Eclipse DDMS tab. I see a data folder with a (+) to the left but when I click, it does not expand.

That would sound like what you will get when testing on hardware, as neither you nor DDMS have access to the contents of `/data` on production hardware.